# Shared Preferences is null in mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, sharedpreferences, dagger-2, android-testing

I am trying to mock a simple shared preferences using Mockito . Since, the examples on google are too complicated to make anything out of it, I decided to go ahead on my own.
The shared preferences are setup using dagger.
It crashes with NPE in the  saveString method in the SharedPreferenceManager class on the putString line.

```
@Module
public class StudentModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static Context getContext(Application application) {
        return application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
}
```

There is a manager class:

```
public class SharedPreferenceManager {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Context context;
    @Inject public SharedPreferenceManager(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, Context context){
        this.sharedPreferences=sharedPreferences;
        this.context=context;
    }
    public String doSomething(){

        return sharedPreferences.getString("s","");
    }
    public void saveString(String s){
        System.out.println(sharedPreferences.getClass().getSimpleName());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("s","bis").apply();

    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class MockTest {
    @InjectMocks
    SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;
    @Mock SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);



    }
    @Test
    public void isSharedPefWorking(){
        sharedPreferenceManager.saveString("bis");
        assertEquals("bis",sharedPreferenceManager.doSomething());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` uses a `SharedPreferences.Editor` which you're not currently mocking.

You would need to do something like the following to mock and verify the behaviour of your `SharedPreferenceManager`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockTest {
    @InjectMocks
    SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;
    @Mock
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Mock
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor;

    final String savedString = "savedString";

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(sharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(sharedPreferencesEditor);
        when(sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(sharedPreferencesEditor);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveString() {
        sharedPreferenceManager.saveString(savedString);
        verify(sharedPreferencesEditor).putString("s", savedString);
    }

    @Test
    public void getString() {
        when(sharedPreferences.getString("s","")).thenReturn(savedString);

        String preferenceString = sharedPreferenceManager.doSomething();

        assertEquals(preferenceString, savedString);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why was stubbing required when the editor was already mocked?

Comment: sharedPreferences.edit() wasn't mocked, which is where the first NPE was occurring. You also need to provide a mock for putString - apply will be called when saving the string which will throw a NPE without it. In the example above these are configured in the setup method. Testing the putString and getString should be done separately - as putString is just using a mock. This means testing the doSomething method requires you provide a value to return when getString is invoked.

Comment: But why do we need to return the editor when it already exists after writing the mock statement?

Comment: why do we need to return the editor? sharedPreferences will return null by default when you call edit(), thats why you need  when(sharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(sharedPreferencesEditor)

Comment: editor.putString("s","bis") will return null by default when you use a mock - in this test case its sharedPreferencesEditor.  Thats why you also need: when(sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(sharedPreferencesEditor)